# bash: trouble getting file size from remote url

Tags: bash, http, carriage-return

I am trying to get file size of remote url in the following manner:

I am trying the below command:

```
curl -sI $url | grep -i content-length | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Its giving `17857797\C-M`

I dont understand why \C-M is adding

Comment: I suspect your '\C-M' is Control-M or carriage return character.

Comment: The carriage return is "added" by [RFC 2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616), as each component of an HTTP response is *required* to end with a carriage-return/line-feed pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append `| dos2unix` or `| tr -d '\r'` to remove carriage-return.